Getting 405 "Method Not Allowed" when I POST to my /api/sendemail endpoint
Here is code in Next.js. This error is happening in deployed environment on Vercel but not on local machine.
GitHub: https://github.com/Bishal-Saud/portfolio2.0
Live: https://bishalsaud.vercel.app/
Error: "POST https://bishalsaud.vercel.app/api/sendemail 405 (Method Not Allowed)"
In the local server it's working fine but in deployed there is issue while sending message /contact and also there is issue while uploading image /article.
Backend code:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    console.log("Incoming request:", req);
    const body = await req.json();
    console.log("Parsed body:", body);
    const { name, email, phone, subject, message } = body;

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
      port: 2525,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.MAILTRAP_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.MAILTRAP_PASSWORD,
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: email,
      to: process.env.RECEIVER_EMAIL,
      subject: subject,
      text: `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\nPhone: ${phone}\n\nMessage:\n${message}`,
    };

    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log("Email sent:", info);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Email sent successfully",
      },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: "Error sending email",
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

export function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      message: "This API endpoint only accepts POST requests.",
    },
    { status: 405 }
  );
}


Frontend code:
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import AnimatedText from "@/Components/AnimatedText";
import { GithubIcon, LinkedInIcon, TwitterIcon } from "@/Components/Icons";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogBody,
  DialogFooter,
  Button,
} from "@material-tailwind/react";
import { FRONTEND_URL } from "@/untill/frontEnd_Url";

export default function Page() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
  });
  const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [dialogMessage, setDialogMessage] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    setIsDialogOpen(true);
    setDialogMessage("Sending...");

    try {
      const res = await fetch(`${FRONTEND_URL}/api/sendemail`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        setDialogMessage("Email sent successfully!");
        setFormData({
          name: "",
          phone: "",
          email: "",
          subject: "",
          message: "",
        });
      } else {
        setDialogMessage("Failed to send email.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setDialogMessage("Error sending email.");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Bishal \ Contact Page</title>
        <meta name="Contact page" content="any description" />
      </Head>
      <main className="min-h-screen w-full text-dark dark:text-white ">
        <AnimatedText text="Contact Me" className="!text-4xl my-10" />
        <div className="flex items-start justify-center gap-5 mt-10 w-full h-full shadow-sm lg:flex-col lg:items-center lg:justify-center">
          <div className="rounded-md flex flex-col items-center justify-end gap-4 h-full w-1/2 lg:w-3/4">
            <h2 className="text-4xl">
              Let&apos;s Work together,{" "}
              <span className="text-primary">Bishal</span>
            </h2>
            <div className="flex items-start justify-start flex-col pt-9">
              <p className="text-xl font-semibold">
                Email:{" "}
                <span className="opacity-30 hover:opacity-100 ease-in-out duration-300 transition-opacity hover:text-primary">
                  bishalsaud15@gmail.com
                </span>
              </p>
              <p className="text-xl font-semibold">
                Phone Number:{" "}
                <span className="opacity-30 hover:opacity-100 hover:text-secondary ease-in-out duration-300 transition-opacity">
                  +9779865742290
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="p-6">
              <h2 className="text-2xl py-4 font-mono">Find out Here</h2>
              <div className="flex gap-6 items-center justify-center">
                <Link
                  className="text-4xl cursor-pointer"
                  href="https://github.com/Bishal-Saud"
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  <GithubIcon />
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className="text-4xl cursor-pointer"
                  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bishal-saud-6a47ba235/"
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  <LinkedInIcon />
                </Link>
                <Link
                  className="text-4xl cursor-pointer"
                  href="https://twitter.com/Bishal_Saud05"
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  <TwitterIcon />
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            className="shadow-sm shadow-dark dark:shadow-light dark:text-white text-dark rounded-lg h-full p-10 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-center w-[35%] md:w-[90%] lg:w-[60%]"
          >
            <div className="your name flex gap-5 xl:flex-col">
              <div className="name flex flex-col">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="font-semibold">
                  Your Name{" "}
                </label>
                <input
                  name="name"
                  value={formData.name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="p-2 bg-light shadow-dark dark:bg-dark dark:shadow-light outline-none border-none shadow-sm mt-2 rounded-sm"
                  required
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter your name"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="number flex flex-col">
                <label htmlFor="number" className="font-semibold">
                  Phone Number{" "}
                </label>
                <input
                  name="phone"
                  value={formData.phone}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="border border-dark p-2 bg-light shadow-dark dark:bg-dark dark:shadow-light outline-none border-none shadow-sm mt-2"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter your number"
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="email flex flex-col">
              <label htmlFor="email" className="font-semibold ">
                Email{" "}
              </label>
              <input
                name="email"
                value={formData.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="border border-dark p-2 bg-light shadow-dark dark:bg-dark dark:shadow-light outline-none border-none shadow-sm mt-2"
                required
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="subject flex flex-col">
              <label htmlFor="subject" className="font-semibold ">
                Subject{" "}
              </label>
              <input
                name="subject"
                value={formData.subject}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="border border-dark p-2 bg-light shadow-dark dark:bg-dark dark:shadow-light outline-none border-none shadow-sm mt-2"
                required
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your subject"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="message flex flex-col">
              <label htmlFor="message" className="font-semibold ">
                Message{" "}
              </label>
              <textarea
                name="message"
                value={formData.message}
                onChange={handleChange}
                className="border border-dark h-28 resize-none p-2 bg-light dark:bg-dark dark:shadow-light shadow-dark outline-none border-none shadow-sm mt-2"
                required
                placeholder="Message"
              />
            </div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="shadow-sm hover:shadow-xl transition-all ease-out duration-300 shadow-dark dark:bg-light dark:text-dark dark:shadow-light mt-4 p-2 text-xl font-semibold"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>

        <Dialog
          open={isDialogOpen}
          handler={setIsDialogOpen}
          className="flex items-center justify-center relative  flex-wrap"
        >
          <DialogHeader>Notification</DialogHeader>
          <DialogBody>{isLoading ? "Sending..." : dialogMessage}</DialogBody>
          <DialogFooter>
            <Button
              variant="outlined"
              color="black"
              onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(false)}
              disabled={isLoading}
            >
              Close
            </Button>
          </DialogFooter>
        </Dialog>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}



Does Vercel or your remote app have some logs you can use to see what is happening inside the code?

yes, i did but there no error log found on vercel but it's shows  405 (Method Not Allowed) in web console when user send message from contact page?

Maybe add some custom logging to your app then, and deploy the debug version. My strategy here would be to see if the calls are getting to your app itself, or Vercel is rejecting them at the firewall.
